# Convert timestamp value from string to timestamp hive

Tags: hive, timestamp, type-conversion, unix-timestamp

I have timestamp value stored as string in my table created in hive, and want to convert it to the timestamp type.

I tried the following code:

```
select date_value, FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_value, 'dd-MMM-YY HH.mm.ss')) from sales limit 2;
```

Original time and result is as following:

```
   Original time              result

07-NOV-12 17.07.03      2012-01-01 17:07:03
25-FEB-13 04.26.53      2012-12-30 04:26:53
```

What's wrong in my script?

Comment: Remove the picture and add text instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yy instead of YY

```
select  date_value
       ,FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_value, 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss'))  as ts

from    sales
;
```

---

```
+--------------------+---------------------+
|     date_value     |         ts          |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| 07-NOV-12 17.07.03 | 2012-11-07 17:07:03 |
| 25-FEB-13 04.26.53 | 2013-02-25 04:26:53 |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but how can I use the column data instead of the array?

Comment: Great, thanks again, just one more thing, how to convert '11' to NOV same as the original time?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use date / timestamp types or at least use the ISO notation YYYY-MM-DD / YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Comment: if you don't mind, please help me get the original format, thanks.

Comment: Please open a new question for that and give a data sample + required results